# Azure mobile services Upload File For Parse( No storage )!

Tags: c#, .net, file-upload, azure-mobile-services

I have a Mobile Service deployed on Azure and i am trying to upload a CSV file for parse on the server.
It is supposed to help as import to the database.

So far i have found this code :

```
public async Task<List<string>> PostAsync()
{
    if (Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent("form-data"))
    {
        string uploadPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/");
        MultipartFormDataStreamProvider streamProvider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(uploadPath);

        await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(streamProvider); // HERE THE CODE THROWS THE EXCEPTION

        List<string> messages = new List<string>();
        foreach (var file in streamProvider.FileData)
        {
            FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(file.LocalFileName);
            messages.Add("File uploaded as " + fi.FullName + " (" + fi.Length + " bytes)");
        }

        return messages;
    }
    else
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Invalid Request!");
        throw new HttpResponseException(response);
    }
}
```

It throws me an error Access is denied to path:

```
    Exception=System.IO.IOException: Error writing MIME multipart body part to output stream. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The stream provider of type 'MyStreamProvider' threw an exception. ---> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'D:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\MobileServicesDotNet\1.0.439\App_Data\demo_2.xlt' is denied.
```

Comment: do you have permission for write the file in the server??

Comment: I deploy to azure and thats why i dont know! 
Anyway I dont want to write something to the server I want to parse the file on the fly. Is it supposed to be writted to be read ?

Comment: Try writing to blob storage instead.

Comment: Actually thats what im going to do!